# How to issue a web request to simulate browser (Namely the TLS handshake / client hello)?

Tags: python, ssl, python-requests, httpwebrequest

i'd like to know how to issue a typical webrequest (For instance using python requests) that will be able to perfectly simulate a webbrowser.  I'm not talking about the user agent which is trivial, but namely the Client Hello message which includes things such as ciphersuite order etc.

For example, i'm issuing a request to https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewMyClient.html , saving the output and comparing the result to what a regular chrome browser displays.  
Here is what i have so far (horrendously ugly...i was playing around with multiple adapters)

```
import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_ import create_urllib3_context
import re
import json
import random
import subprocess
import os



from requests.packages.urllib3.poolmanager import PoolManager
from requests.packages.urllib3.util import ssl_
from urllib3.poolmanager import PoolManager

from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter



from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_ import create_urllib3_context



# This is the 2.11 Requests cipher string, containing 3DES.
CIPHERS = (
    'ECDH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:'
    'RSA+AESGCM'
)


class DESAdapter(HTTPAdapter):
    """
    A TransportAdapter that re-enables 3DES support in Requests.
    """
    def init_poolmanager(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = create_urllib3_context(ciphers=CIPHERS)
        context.options |= ssl.OP_NO_SSLv3
        context.options |= ssl.OP_NO_SSLv2
        context.options |= ssl.OP_NO_SSLv3
        context.options |= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1
        context.options |= ssl.OP_NO_TLSv1_1
        kwargs['ssl_context'] = context

        return super(DESAdapter, self).init_poolmanager(*args, **kwargs)

    def proxy_manager_for(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = create_urllib3_context(ciphers=CIPHERS)
        context.options |= ssl.OP_NO_SSLv3
        kwargs['ssl_context'] = context

        return super(DESAdapter, self).proxy_manager_for(*args, **kwargs)




class Ssl3HttpAdapter(HTTPAdapter):
    """"Transport adapter" that allows us to use SSLv3."""

    def init_poolmanager(self, connections, maxsize, block=False):
        self.poolmanager = PoolManager(
            num_pools=connections, maxsize=maxsize,
            block=block, ssl_version=ssl.OP_NO_SSLv3)




CIPHERS = (
    'ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:'
    'ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:AES128-GCM-SHA256:'
    'AES256-GCM-SHA384:AES128-SHA:AES256-SHA:3DES'   #TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_CHACHA20_POLY1305_SHA256
    )



class TlsAdapter(HTTPAdapter):

    def __init__(self, ssl_options=0, **kwargs):
        self.ssl_options = ssl_options
        super(TlsAdapter, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def init_poolmanager(self, *pool_args, **pool_kwargs):
        ctx = ssl_.create_urllib3_context(ciphers=CIPHERS,options=self.ssl_options)
        self.poolmanager = PoolManager(*pool_args,
                                       ssl_context=ctx,
                                       **pool_kwargs)


s = requests.session()
adapter = TlsAdapter(ssl.OP_NO_SSLv3)
s.mount("https://", adapter)
r = s.get('https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/viewMyClient.html')



if 'Capabilities' in r.text:   
  os.remove("ssl-test-python.html")
  hs = open("ssl-test-python.html", "a")
  hs.write(r.text)
  hs.close()

  os.startfile('ssl-test-python.html')
```

when comparing the saved output to what chrome shows, the main inconsistencies seem to be : 
1)the ciphers are not in the correct order
2)sslv3 should not be enabled
3)way too many 'signature algorithms' are being shown
4)'named groups' are incorrect
5) probably other stuff im missing

Is there any way to work around these issues?  I don't want to use selenium

Answer (score 8):

You can simulate browsers in python perfectly now! Use [curl_cffi](https://github.com/yifeikong/curl_cffi). It's a python binding for the curl-impersonate project.

```
pip install curl_cffi
```

```py
from curl_cffi import requests

# Notice the impersonate parameter
r = requests.get("https://tls.browserleaks.com/json", impersonate="chrome101")

print(r.json())
# output: {'ja3_hash': '53ff64ddf993ca882b70e1c82af5da49'
# the fingerprint should be the same as target browser
```

Answer (score 3):

The biggest reason why the tls fingerprints of python and chrome are different is that python uses openssl and chrome uses boringssl. So you can't use python settings to simulate chrome's tls fingerprint. You can replace openssl with boringssl to compile python from source code. As python doesn't support boringssl, you need to change some source code。

If you can use go. Maybe you can try this, https://github.com/refraction-networking/utls. Go implements tls itself.

Comment: Not quite satisfied with this answer alas. I'd like to a) to mimic the Firefox TLS handshake, b) know what boringssl is and c) if there aren't low-level enough packages (the sockets package for example) on which a TLS handshaker could be written? (if that isn't too naive a question I guess)

Comment: you can try curl_cffi.